# How to get nav_menu_item_id and slug from wp database

Tags: database, page-template

Hi WordPress Experts please help me i want to get nav_menu_item_id and slug from wp database by given a page template like (store.php) this a page template and how we can get nave menu item id and slug that use this page template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Anjum:**

I think the function `get_nav_menu_id_by_page_template()`is what you are looking for? You can place the code for this function in your theme's `functions.php` file, or in a `.php` for a plugin you are writing:

```
function get_nav_menu_id_by_page_template($template) {
  static $nav_menu_id;
  if (!isset($nav_menu_id)) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
  menu.post_id AS menu_id
FROM 
  {$wpdb->postmeta} AS template 
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS menu_id ON menu_id.meta_key='_menu_item_object_id' 
                                         AND menu_id.meta_value=template.post_id
  INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS menu ON menu_id.post_id=menu.post_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND menu.meta_key='_menu_item_object' AND menu.meta_value='page'
  AND template.meta_key='_wp_page_template' AND template.meta_value='%s'
SQL;      
    $nav_menu_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql,$template));
  }
  return $nav_menu_id;
}
```

Once you have the `get_nav_menu_id_by_page_template()` function in your code you can call it in your theme template file like so:

```
<?php $nav_menu_id = get_nav_menu_id_by_page_template('store.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I wondered if it would be faster to extend the nav menu query and let it collect the required information in an array which is accessible from the outside. +1 anyway. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel i am getting an error with it Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL

Comment: @Anjum - Didi you copy my code *exactly*? Do you accidentally indent or put a space in front of `SQL;`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel i have copied and paste your code as it is in my function.php but i am getting this error any other way to....

Comment: @Anjum - Can you give me the entire error message? File name, Line number and all?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel is there a way? to get nav menu id via  `<?php $wpdb->query('query'); ?>`

Comment: @Anjm - Can you give me file name and line number of error? Also, I don't understand what you are trying to ask RE: `$wpdb->query()`; why change the question?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel sorry for late reply to you there is a difference in our time now i am back to my home from my job and now i will be online about 6 hours, please give me an easy way to get nav_menu_id like http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class

Comment: @Anjum - I *have* given you what you need. My example is using the `$wpdb` class with the `get_var()` method, not the `query()` method which is wrong for what you need. You are not providing me with the answers to help me debug your problem. Can you please erase the code and copy my code again *making sure there is no indent or space in front of `SQL;`*. If you still have problems please provide me with a *complete* error message including file names and line numbers.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Now it is working fine and i have get nav_menu_id successfully Special Thanks to you for your special attention and your time to solve my problem Thank You Very Very Very Much

Comment: @Anjum - Glad I could help. For future reference, What did you do differently? Why was did it not work before?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel there is some spaces between code and when i removed spaces and format the code it is working correctly. Thanks again have nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple pages may use the same template. There is no 1:1 relation between templates and pages or nav menu items, so you may get more than one item back.

Templates and item IDs are stored in the table `postmeta`. Look for `_menu_item_object_id` and `_wp_page_template`.

Comment: i am using special template (store.php) for my store (shop) page how can i get menu item id and slug by this template

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIdFromMeta( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pid = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = '$meta_value' AND meta_key = '$meta_key' ORDER BY post_id DESC") );
    if( $pid != '' )
        return $pid;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

it is work fine for me
this solution give me [Rochester Oliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609870/rochester-oliveira) my question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450092/how-to-get-post-id-from-post-meta/5467348#5467348)
Thanks Rochester Oliveira

this return post id but i needed nav menu id